# Apache/Nginx + SSL + Socket.io 80 port

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

Здравствуйте, знатоки.
Весь день бьюсь с решением проблемы совместимости NodeJS (Socket.io) и Apache на одном, 80 порту. Вроде бы завелось, но все равно некоторые ошибки остались.

Задача:
повесить на поддомен socket.io сервер. Чтобы основной сайт будет на exapmle.com, а nodeJS был на socket.example.com.
Устраивал бы и вариант повесить NodeJS на любой другой порт - но в некоторых местах он залочен, что доставляет массу проблем.

Имею такой конфиг Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName socket.example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://example.com:8000

ProxyPass / https://example.com:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Вроде бы все работает... Но консоль Chrome все сыпет ошибку:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=AJRA3DrLNlC_YI_SAAAZ' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"

Как быть? Кто может подсказать? Или может это лучше реализовать на Nginx?

Comment: `proxy_wstunnel` есть у вас? [Отсылка](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27526281/2076787).

Comment: @D-side да, есть. `proxy_module`, `proxy_http_module`, `proxy_wstunnel_module`

Comment: Тогда должно работать, по идее. 400 это "Bad Request", поищите в логах, что об этом думает вебсервер.

Comment: [режим некропостера включен] wss это порт не 80, а шифрованный 443, и возможно ваши настройки апач вообще не учитывает, раз вы из хрома подключаетесь по wss; также, раз в RewriteRule тоже прописан wss вместо ws, то на сервере ноды тоже должны быть настроены ssl-сертификаты, без всего этого работать вроде как не должно